# Improve & Functionalize Queried Array

Tags: php, sql

Need a little help, advise, or link to an example or useful tutorial so I can learn this. As I am very new to programming in general.

I have 11 Select boxes in a form named 'ore1' thru 'ore11' that send data up to $_POST.
This little block turns that into an array that is used in another function.

```
//function calculateValue($sellValue){  -- add when you figure it out
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $i = 11                           //total number of select boxes
      $pdquery = "SELECT * FROM ore
                  WHERE '".$_POST['ore1']."' 
                  LIKE id";
      $result = mysql_query($pdquery);
          $oredata1 = array();
             while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
                  $oredata1 = $row; }
}
else {}
}
```

I'd like like to be able to use this one bit of code with all 11 Select boxes without having to copy it 11 times by getting

```
.$_POST['ore#'].   //5th line
$oredata# = $row;  //10th line
```

to replace # with the appropriate # depending on the select box it is used on.

Any tips??  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Firstly, your code is vulnerable to injection attacks.  Secondly, use either PDO or mysqli.  The mysql_* functions are being deprecated for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML:

```
<select name="ore[]">
...
</select>
<select name="ore[]">
...
</select>
```

In your PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['ore'])){
    foreach($_POST['ore'] as $ore){
        $ore = (int)$ore;
        $pdquery = "SELECT * FROM ore WHERE id = $ore";
        ...
    }
}
```

Also do not use `mysql_*` function since deprecation process has begun

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 11; $i++) {
  $ore = 'ore'.$i;
  $pdquery = "SELECT * FROM ore WHERE '".$_POST[$ore]."' like id";
  ...
```

Answer (score -2):

execute it in a for-loop - from 1 to 11. Then you can use the variable $i to access stuff.

```
// I assume that there is some MySQLi object called $mysqli already present. You'll have to create it if it does not
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $pdquery = 'SELECT * FROM ore WHERE id LIKE ?';
    $oredata = array();

    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($pdquery)) {
        for($i = 1; $i < 12; $i++) {
            $ore = 'ore' . $i;
            if(empty($_POST[$ore])) {
                 continue;
            }
            $oreValue = (int)$_POST[$ore];

            $stmt->bind_Param('i', $oreValue);
            $stmt->execute(); 

            $oredata[$i] = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        }
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

This does NOT take into consideration the fact that there might be more than just those eleven inputs. Using an array on HTML side would certainly be cleaner (And you'd just have to replace the for-loop with a foreach-loop and use the key instead of `$ore`)

Comment: You should ceratinly use an array instead.

Comment: Of course you could ;) I'm not saying it's the only solution, it's just one of the many possibilities.

Comment: PHP doesn't use `+` to concatenate strings, that's Javascript.

Comment: Thanks, I'm always confusing the two ;)

Comment: Your code doesn't have any sense so far. what is `$_POST['ore' . $i];`, what happens if `$_POST['ore11']` doesn't exist? What if on HTML form will be more/less then 11 `select`'s? :)

Comment: He was asking about `.$_POST['ore#'].   //5th line` and `$oredata# = $row;  //10th line` so I just gave him an example on how he could include the `$i` for his examples. But it's still early in the morning and I'm not that awake yet - I'll rewrite my example a bit.